# Why is the python docstring for `os.CLD_CONTINUED` the same as `int().__doc__`?

Tags: python, docstring

I am getting familiar with Python and I thought I would do a dir() walk and examine the doc strings.

I started with the "os" module.

Why is the python docstring for `os.CLD_CONTINUED` the same as `int().__doc__`?

I first noticed that `CLD_CONTINUED` had the same doc string as `CLD_DUMPED`, `CLD_KILLED`, etc.  Then I realized it's the doc string for `int()`.

I imagine this has something to do with object inheritance.

I checked the Python docs and found https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.CLD_CONTINUED which says this about `CLD__*`:

> These are the possible values for si_code in the result returned by waitid().

I then went to https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitid which links me to https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.CLD_EXITED and now I've gone full circle.

Is there someplace else I should look?

I'd like to understand why these si_code docstrings tell me about `int()`.

How can I know when the docstring is not for the thing I'm looking at but for something else? I was really confused at first.

Comment: You are looking at the docstring for an integer value (the one returned by `int()`). Seems weird for sure, but if anything you should look at `int.__doc__`, not `int().__doc__`. Anyway you may want to add the exact Python version you are using, with Python 3.11.1 on Windows `int().__doc__` returns the docstring for `int`.

Comment: `os.CLD_CONTINUED` is simply the integer 6 (on my system at least).  There is no inheritance involved, it's just a plain old 6, exactly the same as any other 6 you might encounter.  It is completely unreasonable to expect it to have a docstring that has anything to do with this particular use of the number 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - help()](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) (**emphasis** is mine):

> If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any other kind of object, a **help page on the object is generated**.

*os.CLD_CONTINUED* (and others as well) is an *int* value so the help for its class is invoked.

> ```py
> (py_pc064_03.10_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/c/Users/cfati]> python
> Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:10) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>
> >>> help(123)
> # Help for 'class int(object)' is displayed
> >>> i = 1
> >>> help(i)
> # Same as above
> >>> import os
> >>> os.CLD_CONTINUED, os.CLD_CONTINUED.__class__
> (6, <class 'int'>)
> >>> help(os.CLD_CONTINUED)
> # Same as above
> >>> help(os.CLD_CONTINUED.__class__)
> # Same as above
> ```